# How to redirect from former CakePHP page a non-CakePHP page using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have some redirects in place from our previous site that used CakePHP. The new site has plain PHP pages. When trying to redirect the following in an .htaccess file I am having problems:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page-here http://samesitename.com/somedirectory/newfilename.php
```

The /old-page-here had the extension .ctp. When I run this in my browser I get a loop with newfilename.php appearing over and over again (as well as the other webaddress information - but not repeated).

I was having a similiarish problem with when CakePHP put page numbers in, e.g.

```
Redirect 301 /olddirectory/old-page-here/2 http://samesitename.com/somedirectory/newfilename-2.php
```

When it would add both directories into the webaddress. Redirecting pages that were within the webroot directory (pulled from the database) that did not end in a slash-number have directed OK.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Forgot to say that we no longer have CakePHP installed.

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess that is likely to be interfering such as mod_rewrite rules? It sounds a bit like you are causing a loop to be formed.

Comment: All I have is a list of Redirect 301s - nothing else.

Comment: what happens if you omit .ctp?

Comment: Basically, when redirecting an old file with the "extension" /2 or /3 (or another number) the redirect goes to /newfile.php/2 etc. I.e. it is adding not getting rid of the extra /2.

Comment: Is there any way to declare any "new folder" such as /1, /2 etc and redirect them to the new file location? E.g. some sort of oldfile/* goes to newfile.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html) could come in handy for building your new urls. As for your trouble with redirecting when cakephp was still installed: I can imagine that this is somewhat complicated to achieve from "outside", as somewhere in the process cake's dispatcher dissolves the address into controller,action, parameters. From the "inside", you can do 
[redirects](http://book.cakephp.org/view/982/redirect) with a status code.

Comment: Great - used RedirectMatch 301 and seems to have done the job. Many thanks, Adam